# Log in with cURL and echo response with cookie

Tags: php, cookies, curl, autologin

I am trying to write an "auto-login" script, that uses curl to log in to a specific site and then echoing the response, so that the user can "bypass" the login.
(For example, to grant one-time logins etc)

Obviously, using the following method, the cookie is stored on the server, not on the client, in cookie.txt.

I've tried setting $_COOKIE, but that won't work, since the URLs (actually subdomains) of the auto-login script and the service to be logged into, are different.

Login works fine. You see the screen as if you were logged in, but clicking any link requires you to login again.

Any ideas? Thanks

The code I've used to auto-login:

```
<?php
$username="email@domain.com"; 
$password="password"; 
$url="http://sub.domain-to-login.com/index.php/sessions/login"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "email=".$username."&password=".$password.'&btn_login=Login'; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;  
?>
```

Comment: This is horribly bad practice. You'll be using the **SAME** cookie.txt for ALL of your users. In effect you're allowing the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc... users to simply take over the 1st user's session. And since you never send the login cookie you've fetched back to your user, if they go and hit the service directly, they won't be logged in, because THEY never received the cookie.

Comment: ok, then i'll store a random string in the session and name the cookie.txt accordingly. Thanks for the heads up, I haven't thought of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you need to replace all links (in $result) from http://sub.domain-to-login.com/index.php/stuff to something like http://mysite.com?url=http://sub.domain-to-login.com/index.php/stuff and then using curl download this site again.
You just cannot set cookie for diffrent site.

Comment: Awful, but that's probably what I'll have to do. Thank you very much for the quick reply.

For future readers: If you have complicated links like I do, do not forget to url-encode the links before putting them in the query string.